# DBHandle function always fails in PB12.net

Tags: database-connection, powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net, powerbuilder-pfc

I have migrated a project from PowerBuilder 12 classic to Powerbuilder 12.net using PFC. Even though in PB12 the connection to the database is successful that is not true for PB12.net.

I have been debugging for the problem and the `DBHandle` function in `of_IsConnected` of `pfc_n_tr` returns false. In PB12 classic this returns true. I have made a database profile which connects successfully though.

This is the code which checks for a successful connection:

```
if this.DBHandle() = 0 then
    return false
else
    return true
end if
```

I added `connect using sqlca;` to see the problem before the check but I got:
`Transaction already connected` in `SQLErrText`.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in DB parameters connection for sql server 2008. 
I changed the `DBMS` variable to `"SNC SQL Native Client(OLE DB)"` and added the `Provider='SQLNCLI10'` to the `DBParm` string.